# Преобразование строки в список с сортировкой в лексикографическом порядке

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Как преобразовать строку, состоящую из слов разделенных пробелами, в список, и отсортировать полученный список в лексикографическом порядке?

Дана строка из слов, разделенных пробелами:

```
s = 'abc a bCd bC AbC BC BCD bcd ABC'
```

преобразовываем ее в список, с разделителем "пробел":

```
a = s.split(' ')
```

получаем:

```
['abc', 'a', 'bCd', 'bC', 'AbC', 'BC', 'BCD', 'bcd', 'ABC']
```

если теперь сделать так:

```
a = a.sort()
print (a)
```

мы не получим ничего, если так:

```
b = a.sort()
print (a)
```

получим отсортированный список

```
['ABC', 'AbC', 'BC', 'BCD', 'a', 'abc', 'bC', 'bCd', 'bcd']
```

почему так? можно ли как-то совместить sort() и split() в одной строчке?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что `a.sort()` просто сортирует `a` (список "просто" становится отсортированным), и ничего не возвращает, а функции не возвращающие ничего в Python по факту возвращают `None`. Если сделать `a = a.sort()`, вы сначала отсортируете `a`, а потом запишите поверх него `None`.

Нужно делать или так:

```
a = a.split(' ')
a.sort()
print(a)
```

Или так, если вам нужно одной строкой:

```
print(sorted(a.split(' '))
```

Разница в том, что метод `list.sort()` меняет исходный список, и ничего не возвращает, а функция `sorted()` не меняет исходный список, а возвращает его отсортированную копию.

Answer (score 6):

Это просто:

```
a = sorted(s.split(' '))
```

В обратном порядке:

```
a = sorted(s.split(' '), reverse=True)
```